# How to fix this: push rejected because it was not a simple fast- forward. use "force: true" to override (spck.io)

Tags: git, github, ide, git-commit, git-push

I use an IDE on my phone called [Spck Editor](https://spck.io/editor) (it has an online version) and sometimes I get this error when I push code to Github:

> Push rejected because it was not a simple fast- forward. Use "force:
> true" to override.

[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h6JD.jpg)

But I cannot find the access to git console to run:

```
git push --force
```

Sorry if the question is too stupid and because my English is not good, please don't be angry :C

Help me, when I got this error I had to manually copy the code and paste it on Github, it was quite time consuming and tiring.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Use `git pull origin your_branch` followed by `git push origin your_branch`

Comment: But my IDE (spck editor) doesn't have a Git terminal

Comment: If Git is installed, you should be able to find the installation and open a Git bash window.

Comment: Sorry, this IDE has Git built in and I use it on my phone, I don't have a computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a commit in one project and then accidentally push this commit, with bypassing code review, to another project, this will fail with the error message 'non-fast forward'. To fix the problem you should check the push specification and verify that you are pushing the commit to the correct project.

```
git fetch
git rebase feature/my_feature_branch
git push origin feature/my_feature_branch
```

After the `git fetch` I recommend to examine situation with `gitk --all`.

Answer (score 0):

### Iam also faced same froblem in spck editor ...

### Make any new file , write something in it. and commit all and push your project .. Then it will worked for me ..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).